# Stage condition is not evaluating to true despite the value being true

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a condition for a stage to run. The condition is `true`, but the stage keeps being skipped and I'm not sure why.

This is the stage:

```
stages:
- stage: UnitTests
  displayName: Run unit tests on service...
  condition: eq(stageDependencies.Changed.Changes.outputs['detectChange.anyServicesChanged'], true)
  dependsOn: Changed
  variables: 
    test: $[ stageDependencies.Changed.Changes.outputs['detectChange.anyServicesChanged'] ]
  jobs:
  - job: UnitTests
    displayName: Running unit tests...
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo $(test)
```

Or assigning it to a variable:

```
stages:
- stage: UnitTests
  displayName: Run unit tests on service...
  variables: 
    test: $[ stageDependencies.Changed.Changes.outputs['detectChange.anyServicesChanged'] ]
  condition: eq(variables.test, true)
  # dependsOn: Changed
  jobs:
  - job: UnitTests
    displayName: Running unit tests...
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo $(test)
```

However, if I comment out the `condition` and `dependsOn`, sure enough the `echo $(test)` does print out `true`.

```
stages:
- stage: UnitTests
  displayName: Run unit tests on service...
  # condition: eq(stageDependencies.Changed.Changes.outputs['detectChange.anyServicesChanged'], true)
  # dependsOn: Changed
  variables: 
    test: $[ stageDependencies.Changed.Changes.outputs['detectChange.anyServicesChanged'] ]
  jobs:
  - job: UnitTests
    displayName: Running unit tests...
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo $(test)

Starting: Bash
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.182.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
echo true
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/119fb181-f890-4c1c-bffa-94142b0d51d9.sh
true
Finishing: Bash
```

This is the stage where changes are detected:

```
stages:
- stage: Changed
  displayName: Checks for changes in services and configs...
  jobs:
  - job: Changes
    displayName: Checking for changes in services and configs...
    steps:
    - bash: |
        mapfile -t servicesChanged < <(git diff  HEAD origin/production --name-only | awk -F'/' 'NF!=1{print $1}' | sort -u)
        echo "Total Changed: ${#servicesChanged[@]}"
        if [[ ${#servicesChanged[@]} > 0 ]]; then
          echo "Any services changed: True"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=anyServicesChanged;isOutput=true]true"
        fi
      name: detectChange
```

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here that it keeps skipping this stage when the `condition` and `dependsOn` is active. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use this condition(*Stage depending on job output*) on a stage, you must use the `dependencies` variable, not `stageDependencies`.Thus the following syntax should work.

```
- stage: UnitTests
  displayName: Run unit tests on service...
  condition: eq(dependencies.Changed.outputs['Changes.detectChange.anyServicesChanged'], true)
  dependsOn: Changed
```

See: [Stage depending on job output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#stage-depending-on-job-output) for details.